# How to insert image from a path in mysql blob through php and without using browse button

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the code for image upload when you create a browse input tag

```
$imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
    $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO output_images(imageType ,imageData)
    VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
    $current_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysql_error());
```

But i want to upload it from a path without using input tag, because i got file which contains multiple image name with there path and i want to insert it in database